# Why does my first label show up behind my pie chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I am looking at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSYPK/).  When I add the labels to my pie chart the first label appears behind the chart while the rest are added on top of the chart.  The only reason you see the label in the example is because I've added `fill-opacity: .8` to the chart.

I believe the problem is somewhere in this code:

```
pieLabels.enter()
  .append("text");

pieLabels.attr("class", "pie_labels")
  .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    d.outerRadius = rad + 200;
    d.innerRdius = (rad + 200) / 2;

    var c = arc.centroid(d);
    var x = c[0] + rad - t;
    var y = c[1] + rad - t;
    return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function (d, i) {
    return d.data.key + ': ' + d.data.value;
  });

pieLabels.exit()
  .remove();
```

Is there a way to add in labels to make sure that they appear on top of my pie chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this because in your `initPieChart` function, you're appending a single text element. Thus, subsequent `.selectAll()`s will select this existing element and change it. The actual pie segments are appended after that single text element and therefore overlap it.

You can easily fix this by deleting the lines that append the single text element in the init function. Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSYPK/2/).

Answer (score 1):

it's because you append the text before the pie chart itself, the creation of svg files happens on layers, so first things written get drawn before the others, so you'd have to move the text after the pie chart is rendered to have it on top. <strike>Or you could set the z-index of the text, it should work too.</strike>